# alignment of sections and memory within an EXE file

Tags: compiler-construction, executable, il, portable-executable

What are the alignment of sections and memory within an EXE file I need to specify when creating using in the Mosa IL compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically the same as the page size, 4K for most CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

The sections within the PE file must be aligned on 4k boundaries.

You can involve the MOSA compiler properly like this:

```
mosacl.exe -a=x86 -f=PE --pe-file-alignment=4096 --map=hello.map -b=mb0.7 -o hello.exe
```

Comment: That is false, refer to the portable executable format. It is recommended not required.